# How to avoid multiple asynctask in one activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an android activity that needs to run six asynctask classes.
I created my activity and it works fine, but with those 6 classes my code is so hard to comprehend or edit.
Maybe its dump but i am new in android so what i need is to know how to simplify my code a bit: is there a possibility to make all async tasks in one class knowing that they have different functionalities

Comment: Looking at a relevant portion of your code would be helpful. As it is now the question is too broad.

Comment: You could offload the AsyncTasks into another class, or each into their own task, if applicable. Obviously, you'd need to pass an activity reference to update the UI. Also keep in mind that as of Android 3.x, only *one* AsyncTask executes at a time by default (you can change it, but most don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one Async Task only and do different things in it by passing a functionality ID, if you may, as a parameter.

Although, I strongly recommend you to create 6 different files, each containing your Async Task class (if they have truly different functionality) and put them in a package "Async Tasks", if you may.

If, for instance, you need to do different sort of requests to a server, you should only have one Async Task, different parameters (such as URL, post parameters, etc) and handle the result different in your onPostExecute method according to the type of request you have done: send an event to your activity that calls the proper method to handle the result.

You can use this technique to manage you more-general Async Tasks

Comment: Intresting idea becose in all my asynctask i i send differents parameters but with the same structure. So if i do that i will need to do some tests on the results given from the server to know what task was running and what i need to do next, but would that be ok for the clarity of my code ? like @ataulm said in the privious answer maybe it will complicate more my code

Comment: If what happens in your doInBackground method is the same for every parameters, but the result is different, this is the way to do it. It is in best practices for every programming language that you shouldn't have the same code written more than once. Try sending an ID parameter in your doInBackground method, save it right at the beginning in a public property of the Async Task and, in your onPostExecute

Comment: send different events to your activity regarding your ID. You shouldn't literally manage your results here, in onPostExecute, just see what sort of request has been done and send the proper event to your activity. There, you can process the result. This way, you keep your code clean AND don't write 6 classes with the same code in doInBackground

Answer (score 1):

> is there a possibility to make all async tasks in one class

Yes, but don't. You mention "simplifying" your code - putting more functionality into one class will make it difficult to understand what that class is responsible for.

The better option would be to add 6 different implementations of AsyncTask, and create new instances of them in your Activity. The names you use for the classes should represent what they do, and they should do as little as possible.

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't too broad finally. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could move your `AsyncTasks` to separate files. You could pass the Activity to your `AsyncTasks` constructors.

Might be you also could combine some of your tasks into one.

Comment: How comes you can not move your classes, they are yours you can do whatever you want with them